# Do ES6 arrow functions have their own arguments or not?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I don’t know whether **arrow functions** bind `arguments` to a lexical scope or not.

Take a look at this example (the same concept can be used for `this`):

```
var b = function() { return () => console.log(arguments); };
b(1,2,3)(4,5,6); // different result of chrome vs FF.
```

When I run this on Chrome, I get `[1,2,3]`, but on Firefox, I get `[4,5,6]`. What’s going on?

Comment: I would say Firefox has got it right this time, although I definitely understand why Chrome behaves the way it does. Nice find!

Comment: @StephanBijzitter according to answers it doesn't :/

Comment: @StephanBijzitter no, Chrome got it right.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> Any reference to `arguments`, `super`, `this`, or `new.target` within an
>   *ArrowFunction* must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing
>   environment.

Therefore, the correct answer would be `[1,2,3]`. Firefox has fixed the problem in version 43 ([bug 889158](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=889158)).

Answer (score 11):

No, arrow functions don't have their own `arguments`, `this`, `super`, or `new.target`.

See the note at [14.2.16 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> An *ArrowFunction* does not define local bindings for `arguments`, `super`, `this`, or `new.target`. Any reference to `arguments`, `super`, `this`, or `new.target` within an *ArrowFunction* must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment. Typically this will be the `Function Environment` of an immediately enclosing function.

Answer (score 2):

> Arrow functions don't have their own arguments object.
>
> Arrow functions do not expose an arguments object to their code:
>   `arguments.length`, `arguments[0]`, `arguments[1]`, and so forth do not
>   refer to the arguments provided to the arrow function when called.

[`Arrow_functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_arguments)

For this example

```js
var b = function() {
  return () => console.log(arguments);
};

b(1,2,3)(4,5,6);
```

correct answer should be `[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score -1):

What's going on is in fact pretty simple. Chrome does not seem to add an `arguments` object to the scope of the inner (arrow) function, while Firefox does.

This means that the arguments logged in Chrome are the arguments passed to the parent function, which is a "normal" function.

Firefox believes (and in my opinion they're right to) that the arrow functions should also have the `arguments` object, and thus that is why they log the second set of numbers.

As others said, what Firefox does is against the specification.

Comment: The ECMAScript spec is what it is. Chrome implements the spec and is therefore correct. Firefox is incorrect regardless of what opinions might exist.

Comment: And that's what the parenthesis are for ;-)

Comment: What do you mean Firefox "has the right" to believe what ECMAScript behaviour should be ?

Comment: So I'm being downvoted for an opinion now?